# Creating onchange event and select list id using Javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dom-events

I managed to create a dynamic three dropdown list using Javascript code and it is given below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setOptions(chosen, selbox) {

selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');
setTimeout(setOptions(' ',document.myform.optthree),5);
}
if (chosen == "1") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--Select--','11');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Zone','12');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Circle','13');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Division','14');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Sub Division','15');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section','16');
setTimeout(setOptions('11',document.myform.optthree),5);
 }
if (chosen == "2") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--Select--','21');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('District','22');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Taluk','23');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Hobli','24');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Village','25');
setTimeout(setOptions('21',document.myform.optthree),5);
}
if (chosen == "11") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');
 }
if (chosen == "12") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--All Zones--',' ');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Mangalore','Mangalore');
}
if (chosen == "13") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--All Circles--',' ');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Mangalore','Mangalore');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Udupi','Udupi');
  }
if (chosen == "14") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--All Divisions--',' ');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Mangalore','Mangalore');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Bantwal','Bantwal');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Udupi','Udupi');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Kundapur','Kundapur');
}
if (chosen == "15") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--All Sub Divisions--',' ');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Attavara','Attavara');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Mannagudda','Mannagudda');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Bantwal','Bantwal');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Vittal','Vittala');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Udupi','Udupi');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Manipal','Manipal');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Kundapur','Kundapur');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Brahmavar','Brahmavar');
}
if (chosen == "16") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--All Sections--',' ');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 1','Section 1');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 2','Section 2');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 3','Section 3');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 4','Section 4');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 5','Section 5');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 6','Section 6');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 7','Section 7');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 8','Section 8');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 9','Section 9');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 10','Section 10');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 11','Section 11');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 12','Section 12');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 13','Section 13');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 14','Section 14');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 15','Section 15');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Section 16','Section 16');
}
 if (chosen == "21") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');
 }
 if (chosen == "22") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--All Districts--',' ');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('District 1','District 1');
 }
if (chosen == "23") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--All Taluks--',' ');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Taluk 1','Taluk 1');
 }
if (chosen == "24") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--All Hoblis--',' ');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Hobli 1','Hobli 1');
 }
if (chosen == "25") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('--All Villages--',' ');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Village 1','Village 1');
}
 }
 </script>
</head>


 <body>

    <form name="myform">

  <select name="optone" onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value,document.myform.opttwo);">
  <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
  <option value="1">Office Heirarchy</option>
  <option value="2">Geographical Heirarchy</option>
     </select><br> <br>

   <select name="opttwo" onchange="setOptions(document.myform.opttwo.options[document.myform.opttwo.selectedIndex].value,document.myform.optthree);">
    <option value=" " selected="selected">Please select one of the options above first</option>
   </select><br> <br>

  <select name="optthree">
     <option value=" " selected="selected">Please select one of the options above first</option>
   </select><br> <br>

    </form>

  </body>
    <html>
```

It works fine. Now I want to add the `onchange` event and **id** to the third dropdown list. i.e., for zone list id is id1 and `onchange` function is function(f1), and for circle list id is id2 and `onchange` function is function(f2) and so on. Anyone please help me to add this id and function using Javascript.

Comment: You want to do it with javascript only or jquery can be used??

Comment: What do you want the third one to do? You really should investigate JSON and shorten your script using _this_ as in `onchange="setOptions(this[this.selectedIndex].value,this.form.opttwo);"`

Comment: Javascript or jquery both can be used @Nishu Tayal.

Comment: I want to load the options in third dropdown using **onchange** event. Also i want to give id to that dropdown list.

Comment: Right now, options are loaded in third dropdown, as i checked your code (http://jsfiddle.net/XugAx/) and you can assign ID to that dropdown.

Comment: Yes @Nishu Tayal. But when selecting the third dropdown, i want to load the particular map of that location using **onChange=somefunction()**. So how can i add onChange event to my third dropdown? Also i want to assign id to the third dropdown. Actually i uploaded the map data in fusion table and i uploaded the map here https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/attach/a2f994dea3b78b1/select+5+layers.html?part=4&authuser=0&view=1.

Comment: Actually i want to add some javascript codes like        element.setAttribute("onchange", function(){somefuction();}); to dynamically load the options in third dropdown when selected and also add some id to it using      element.setAttribute("id", myid);   But i don't know where to add these codes in my program. So i want help.

Comment: The map you uploaded seems to do something. What part is the problem? The script in that page also does not seem to match the code you posted in the question

Comment: There is a five layers in my map and have 5 dropdowns for each layer. Now i want to combine all the dropdown using the code given in this question. But the problem is i unable to use the onchange event in the above code i given. For this i want the help @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the actual answer was

```
document.getElementsByName("optthree")[0].onchange=function() { changeMap4(this.value)}
```

and

```
document.getElementsByName("optthree")[0].id=".."
```

For other stuff I did while waiting for information look here:

Struggling a little bit with the resetting of the selects when a select up the chain was changed. Maybe a rewrite is needed where I can recurse, but I do not recurse well ;)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mhj4p/)

```
var sels = [
  { text:"Please select",value:"",subs:[]},
  { text:"Office Hierarchy",
    value:1,
    subs: [
          { text:'--Select--', value:'11', subs:[{ text:'Please select one of the options above first', value:' '}]},
          { text:'Zone', value:'12', 
            subs:[ 
              { text:'--All Zones--', value:' '},
              { text:'Mangalore', value:'Mangalore'}
              ]
          },
          { text:'Circle', value:'13', 
            subs:[
              { text:'--All Circles--', value:' '},
              { text:'Mangalore', value:'Mangalore'},
              { text:'Udupi', value:'Udupi'}
              ]
          },
          { text:'Division', value:'14', 
            subs:[              
              { text:'--All Divisions--', value:' '},
              { text:'Mangalore', value:'Mangalore'},
              { text:'Bantwal', value:'Bantwal'},
              { text:'Udupi', value:'Udupi'},
              { text:'Kundapur', value:'Kundapur'}
            ]
          },
          { text:'Sub Division', value:'15',
            subs:[
              { text:'--All Sub Divisions--', value:' '},
              { text:'Attavara', value:'Attavara'},
              { text:'Mannagudda', value:'Mannagudda'},
              { text:'Bantwal', value:'Bantwal'},
              { text:'Vittal', value:'Vittala'},
              { text:'Udupi', value:'Udupi'},
              { text:'Manipal', value:'Manipal'},
              { text:'Kundapur', value:'Kundapur'},
              { text:'Brahmavar', value:'Brahmavar'}              
            ]
          },
          { text:'Section', value:'16',
            subs:[
              { text:'--All Sections--', value:' '},
              { text:'Section 1', value:'Section 1'},
              { text:'Section 2', value:'Section 2'},
              { text:'Section 3', value:'Section 3'},
              { text:'Section 4', value:'Section 4'},
              { text:'Section 5', value:'Section 5'},
              { text:'Section 6', value:'Section 6'},
              { text:'Section 7', value:'Section 7'},
              { text:'Section 8', value:'Section 8'},
              { text:'Section 9', value:'Section 9'},
              { text:'Section 10', value:'Section 10'},
              { text:'Section 11', value:'Section 11'},
              { text:'Section 12', value:'Section 12'},
              { text:'Section 13', value:'Section 13'},
              { text:'Section 14', value:'Section 14'},
              { text:'Section 15', value:'Section 15'},
              { text:'Section 16', value:'Section 16'}
            ]
          }
       ]              
   },
  { text:"Geographical Heirarchy",
    value:2,
    subs: [
      { text:'--Select--', value:'21', subs:[{ text:'Please select one of the options above first', value:' '}]},
      { text:'District', value:'22',
        subs:[
          { text:'--All Districts--', value:' '},
          { text:'District 1', value:'District 1'}
        ]
      },
      { text:'Taluk', value:'23',
        subs:[
          { text:'--All Taluks--', value:' '},
          { text:'Taluk 1', value:'Taluk 1'}                
        ]
      },
      { text:'Hobli', value:'24',
        subs:[
          { text:'--All Hoblis--', value:' '},
          { text:'Hobli 1', value:'Hobli 1'}
        ]
      },
      { text:'Village', value:'25',
        subs:[
          { text:'--All Villages--', value:' '},
          { text:'Village 1', value:'Village 1'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Thank u for the code. Now i want to dynamically load the map by giving onchange event to the third dropdown. Can u please help me??? The map link is here: https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/attach/a2f994dea3b78b1/select+5+layers.html?part=4&authuser=0&view=1 and my dropdown menu of the code given in this question is here: http://jsfiddle.net/XugAx/

Comment: I managed to edit upto this level. Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rVLNA/ and full result is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rVLNA/embedded/result/                         Try to select different sections in the third dropdown in the result and see how the map is loading. In the same way, I want to load other dropdown (zone, circle, etc) also using onchange event. But i confused where to add the **element.setAttribute("onchange", function(){somefuction();});** and **element.setAttribute("id", myid);** to my code.

Comment: I am so sorry, I really do not understand your question. - I would assign all onload handlers in the head: `document.getElementById("someId").onchange=function() {...}` Please see my fiddle in the answer

Comment: Ok.. I'l explain again. This is my code :http://jsfiddle.net/XugAx/ Now on selecting first dropdown, the corresponding options in the second will trigger and when selecting options in second dropdown the corresponding values in third dropdown will trigger, right? For example, in my code, **zone, circle, division, etc** list will load in 2nd when selecting **office heirarchy**, in 1st dropdown. Similarly, when selecting **zone** in 2nd dropdown **All zones, Mangalore** will load. Or when selecting the **circle** circle list will load. And it is done by onchange event. right?

Comment: Now i want the same action in third dropdown also. That is on selecting **Office heirarchy  -> Zone --> Mangalore** in third list the map should load Mangalore zone. That is, i want to add onchange event to third dropdown too. But the problem is that the select list  in 3rd dropdown corresponds to zone has one function, and select list in 3rd dropdown corresponds to circle has another function and so on. So how can i add onchange event to third dropdown using javascript? So that different lists in 3rd dropdown will change according to different function.

Comment: In my third dropdown list, **zone** list has the id _searchString5_ and it should trigger using the function `onChange="changeMap5(this.value)"`. Similarly, **circle** list has id _searchString4_ and trigger using `onChange="changeMap4(this.value)"` and so on. So how can i or where can i add this id and onchange event in my code which is here http://jsfiddle.net/XugAx/ Please help...

Comment: What is wrong with `<select name="optthree" onchange="setCircle(this)">`

Comment: My third dropdown list should `<select name="optthree" id="searchString5" onChange="changeMap5(this.value);">` for **zone** list. Similarly for **Circle** list, it is `<select name="optthree" id="searchString4" onChange="changeMap4(this.value);">` and for **Division** list it is `<select name="optthree" id="searchString3" onChange="changeMap3(this.value);">` and so on upto **Section**. But i can't put this in the html code. I want to add this via javascript so that when loading the perticular list, corresponding id and & onchange function will load.

Comment: so `document.getElementsByName("optthree")[0].onchange=function() { changeMap4(this.value)}`

Comment: Then where to put the id tag and what is meant by [0]? Can you give me the example code?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("optthree")[0].id=".."` but why change ID?

Comment: Because my each list in 3rd dropdown has different id's too. Plese see my complete code what i done already is here : http://jsfiddle.net/rVLNA/1/ In it i made 5 seperate lists as _Select a Zone, Select a Circle, Select a Division, etc_ each with different id's. Also i made a 3 level dropdown at the top. Now i want to combine all that five list to a single three level dropdown.

Comment: I added the code that u given `document.getElementsByName("optthree")[0].onchange=function() { changeMap4(this.value)}` and `document.getElementsByName("optthree")[0].id=".."` to my program and works exactly as i needed. See this link : http://jsfiddle.net/7aYPG/1/ **Thank you very much for the help** @mplungjan. I always grateful to you. Thank you once again :) :) :)